# How secure is Windows Hello when used with Intel 3D facial recognition?

Tags: authentication, windows, biometrics, windows-10

Windows 10 mobile devices, Surface Laptops, and several other 3rd parties integrate an [Intel Realsense 3D camera.](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/realsense-overview.html)

Windows Hello extends this 3D camera to support user authentication.

- What security parameters are used to describe the relative security of this authentication?  (for example, fingerprint readers use quantity of points to determine the integrity of the scan)
- What other relevant information is useful for comparing this biometric authentication

Comment: Since you cannot change biometric parameters (e.g. your face!), I personally think that biometric logins can only ever be a convenience feature not really a security one. Certainly not a high-security feature. Well managed multi-factor authentication will always be stronger. However, for many use cases, it is going to be "good enough"

Comment: @JulianKnight This question is regarding the technical quality of the biometric data received. I'm looking for a summary of data points, class, resolution, vertices, etc that are used for this feature.

Comment: ... also not authentication is the same.  Windows Hello implies "something you have", which is the computer with the non-transferrable hello data.  Akin to the thumbprint sensor on many devices.  You do have valid points though.

Comment: "This question is regarding" - Yes, that's why that is a comment and not an answer. ;-)

Comment: Is the hello data non-transferable? I've not checked whether it syncs to other machines along with much other data. Good point though.

Comment: @JulianKnight  - Of course, I only wrote that for newcomers, to clarify my desire.

Comment: @JulianKnight - Initial readings over the docs seemed to indicate that.  Would love to verify, or determine the realm of transferability (akin to Apple Keychain)

Comment: I guess you need 2 devices, both with hello and with the same Microsoft account login. I do have 2 but they have different logins because I'm fed up of certain settings being synch'd between machines with the same login! I always forget and it gets messy :-{

Comment: I am fairly sure Windows Hello does not "use" the new features that Intel's RealSense offers. So it would be just as secure as a normal webcam. (Ie.: Not much.) This might change in the future of course. Maybe in the next update after Creator they will add support.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft's website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/design/device-experiences/windows-hello-face-authentication), there are 3 measurements that represent the accuracy of Windows Hello's facial recognition, which are: False Positives; True Positives; and False Negatives. These are explained in the quote below

> Microsoft represents the accuracy of Windows Hello face in three main
>   measures, which are: False Positives, True Positives, and False
>   Negatives.
>
> False positives:
>
> Also called False Acceptance Rate, represents the likelihood a random
>   user who obtains access to your device will be recognized as you. This
>   number should be as low as possible.
>
> With windows 10, the results are less than 0.001% or 1/100,000 FAR
>   (False Acceptance Rate)
>
> True Positives:
>
> The True Positive rate represents the likelihood a user will be
>   correctly matched to their profile each time they are registered by
>   the camera This number should be high
>
> The results with windows 10 are greater than 95% with a single
>   enrolled user
>
> False negatives:
>
> Represents the likelihood a user is not matched to their enrolled
>   profile. This number should be low.
>
> The results with Windows 10 are less than 5% with a single enrolled
>   user.

Comment: this is a generic description of biometrics in general, none of this answers the question